# JSP - AJAX and Controller gets the Object but does not update modelAttriibute

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, controller, modelattribute

When the page loads, it populate the table.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/access" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String access(ModelMap model) {

    List<UserDTO> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);

    UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "access";
}
```

When the user clicks Edit on one row, ajax will be called.

```
function getDetails(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "get",
        data : {id: id},
        url : "get-details",
        cache : false,
        success : function(response) {
            // code here
        },
    });
}
```

On the controller, it will get the UserDTO with the id provided.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/get-details" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getDetails(@RequestParam("id") String id, ModelMap model) {
    UserDTO user = userService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return access; //'access' is the current page
}
```

In my jsp I have...

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">
```

My problem is that the attributes of "user" remains null and not updated.
Note that after calling ajax that calls controller, userService.findById has result.
What am I missing?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I think I really need to update modelAttribute="user" in my jsp using the response after ajax call.
Because I am using the "user" attribute and binding it to fields and errors

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id" />

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-14">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="firstName">First
                            Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName"
                                class="form-control input-sm" />
                            <div class="has-error">
                                <form:errors path="firstName" class="help-inline" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

If I will set directly the input field, I am having an error if the form is submitted with error (e.g. empty fields)

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/SSSBackEnd] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)

Comment: Your request mappging handling the ajax call is returning a string, what means it is a view, what means Spring, using your view resolver configuration, is going to translate into html code. When using ajax you should use @ResponseBody and return a json object, updating the front-end dynamically using javascript.

Comment: Thanks! Got the idea. But when I get a json object, how can I use that to update the modelAttribute="user"?
Note that, it is on another jsp which is a modal.

Comment: To explain further, for example I have A.jsp which has the ajax call and response with json object. I need that in my B.jsp which is a modal which will be shown after I got the response from ajax call.

success : function(response) {
            // response is now a json object

// i will show modal, 
$('#myModal').modal('show');

//but inside this modal, i have 

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">

I want to update "user" using the response I got

Comment: In that case you do not need to use an ajax method. Just open the modal window pointing to the `get-details` url, pasing the id, like `get-details?id=your_id`

Comment: how can i point my modal to get-details url? because for now i am just calling $('#myModal').modal('show'); within the same url. If I'm going to use a button click my modal is set as data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"

Comment: Remove @ResponseBody.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is a javascript modal, not a explorer window. My bad. In that case you need to update the fields manually using javascript once you receive the json object on your ajax success method.

Comment: @akuma8 Thanks for reply but nothing happens.

Comment: @alfcope How can I do that? (sorry I just have very basic understanding on javascript and ajax and jsp)

Comment: I tried <%session.setAttribute("user",response);%> but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is to set model attribute in controller and let it return the jsp name itself (access). (no changes made)

Then on Ajax response, I added an update to access html using this code.

```
$('#accessid').html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you want to get your object in `success: function(response){ }` so what you should doing is this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/get-details" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public UserDTO getDetails(@RequestParam("id") String id, ModelMap model) {
    UserDTO user = userService.findById(id);
  return user; //return the object not the view name
}
```

And in your ajax part :

```
success: function(response){
 //response = UserDTO
 alert(response.name); //for example 
}
```

Comment: I did. And I now have an ajax response, but how can I update my modal modelAttribute="user" using the response?

Comment: I tried, $('#user').val(response); and <%session.setAttribute("user",response);%> but no luck

Comment: Create a session and put it in it.

Comment: Like this one? <%session.setAttribute("user",response);%>

Comment: `response` is an object so you can't do this : `$('#user').val(response);` but you can do sthg like `$('#user').val(response.name);`

Comment: But "user" value is equivalent to "response". Since I am using "user" in modal modelAttribute="user", and I have path="firstName", path="lastName", and so on.

Comment: We're getting there. :) I just need to update modelAttribute in my modal to the response I got. Something like user = response so that when I use modelAttribute="user" and path="firstName", I can get the firstName from response.

Comment: Add an id in each field and  make sthg like :`$('#firstName').val(response.firstName);` and `$('#lastName').val(response.lastName);`

Comment: Okay. Why should I set the whole "response" to the "user" if I can set it in each field. Haha. You got it @akuma8

Comment: I can't up vote, it says I should have 15+ reputation. Anyway, thanks a lot @akuma8 !